# Issue with PlotRange and Graphics3D in version 12.2

Tags: graphics3d, bugs, version-12.2

When `Boxed` is set to `False`, `PlotRange` no longer works. I feel this should be considered a bug.

Test cases

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[{Sphere[]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-r, r}, {-r, r}, {-r, r}}, 
    Boxed -> boole], 
  {boole, {True, False}}, 
  {r, 1, 5}]

Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
    {{Opacity[0.5], Cone[{{0, 0, -5}, {0, 0, 0}}], 
      Red, InfinitePlane[{0, 0, z0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, Cos[α], Sin[α]}}]}}, 
    Boxed -> boole, 
    PlotRange -> 6],
  {boole, {True, False}}, 
  {{α, Pi/6}, 0, Pi}, 
  {{z0, -3}, -5, 0}]
```

Comment: MMA version 12.1 seems to work.

Comment: I can confirm that this happens in 12.2 (tried on the cloud) but not in 12.0 (on desktop). I agree that it looks like a bug. Please report it to Wolfram Support (https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback).

Comment: Tried it on desktop both 12.1 and 12.2. Works as one would expect in 12.1, responds to PlotRange wheater Boxed is True or False. But in 12.2 the PlotRange is "lost" when Boxed is False. So it is a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure what the 2nd Manipulate is supposed to show.  There's a slight difference in padding when the box is removed, but that seems OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've confirmed this is a known regression caused by bug fixes in the option `SphericalRegion`.  Sorry!  It is fixed in our nightly build so will make it to whatever our next release is.  You can work around it by changing the style of the box instead of setting it to `False`, as follows:

```
Manipulate[
    Graphics3D[{Sphere[]},PlotRange->{{-r,r},{-r,r},{-r,r}},BoxStyle->Opacity[bool]],
    {bool,{0,1}},
    {r,1,5}
]
```